# How to make a view visible when a button is clicked and make that view invisible when the button is again clicked?

Tags: android

I have a layout which is invisible when the activity starts.When I click on a button the layout becomes visible.My requirement is when I click the button for the second time, the layout should be invisible.I know this is a silly question but as I am a new to android, I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following code to toggle the visibility of the view:

```
v.setVisibility(v.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE ? View.VISIBLE
                : View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement by using boolean FLAG.

e.g.   Declare

```
boolean visibility_Flag = false;


button..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                                     if(visibility_Flag){
                                          YourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                         visibility_Flag = false;
                                      } else {
                                              YourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                         visibility_Flag =true;                               
                                      }

                                    }
                            });
```